# Find the key for a given value of a Dictionary element in Swift

Tags: swift

My code looks like this:

```
var dict = ["a": 1, "b": 2]

var valueInDict = 1
```

My question is whether it's possible to access the key, in this case "a", using only the value.

Comment: When you have a problem like this one, the first step is to check the available tools, e.g. public API, which would show you the `allKeys` property of `NSDictionary`. This isn't an optimal way to solve the problem in general, for a better result you might want to consider implementing a storage that will better suit your needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to get *the* key by its value, because multiple keys can have the same value. For example, if you make a dictionary like this

```
let dict = [
    "a" : 7
,   "b" : 3
,   "c" : 11
,   "d" : 7
,   "e" : 3
,   "f" : 11
]
```

and try to find the key of value `7`, there would be two such keys - `"a"` and `"d"`.

If you would like to find all keys that map to a specific value, you can iterate the dictionary like this:

```
let search = 7
let keys = dict // This is a [String:int] dictionary
    .filter { (k, v) -> Bool in v == search }
    .map { (k, v) -> String in k }
```

This produces keys of all entries that have the `search` value, or an empty array when the `search` value is not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Use the fact that Dictionary values and keys properties are documented to have the same order:

```
if let index = dict.values.indexOf(valueInDict) {
    let key = dict.keys[index]
    print(key)
}
```